# Why does $f(x)=x$ not have a maximum on open interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, real-numbers

On a closed interval $[0,1]$ it evidently has $\max$ at $1$ - so wouldn't the $\max$ for the open interval just be whatever decimal number is just before $1$?

Comment: Can you say what that particular decimal number is?

Comment: It would – if there were such a thing. But there's no such thing as "the number just before 1".

Comment: So then is it suffice to say that for an increasing 1-1 function with an open interval, there cannot be a max?

Comment: @Davin Yes. Since it's 1-1, it's strictly increasing. If $c_0 \in (a,b)$ is the maximum, then consider $f\left(\frac{b + c_0}{2}\right)>f(c_0)$, contradiction.

Comment: @Davin If a function is defined on an open interval and strictly increasing, then it cannot have a max (and not a min either). It can have a _supremum_, though, and that's the "this ought to be the max" value that you're tihnking of. The "this ought to be the minimum" is called the _infimum_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume you would have **such** a decimal number, lets call it $x$. Then clearly $x<1$.

Now take a look at $\frac{1+x}{2}$. You observe $\frac{1+x}{2}<1$ and $\frac{1+x}{2}>x$, thus this number is still in $(0,1)$ but larger than $x$ and this yields a contradiction, since $x$ could not have been **such** a decimal number.

Answer (score 1):

> wouldn't the max for the open interval just be whatever decimal number is just before 1?

Yes, if there existed a number "just before $1$", then that number would be the maximum of $f$.

But such a number doesn't exist.

---

To actually prove that $f$ does not have a maximum, you can prove the statement

> For every $x\in(0,1)$, $f(x)<f\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)$ and $\frac{x+1}{2}\in (0,1)$.

from which the fact that

> for every $x\in(0,1)$, $x$ is not a maximum of $f$

clearly follows.

Answer (score 1):

You use there words HAS a max and THE max yourself.

The concept that works for "just before one and such" is a Supremum which is much much neater.

Every max is a sup, but a sup need not be a max: a sup need not be a value attained in the domain.

But a sup has the property that it is closer to $1$ in this case than any other upper bound. Every upper bound is either greater than the supremum or equal to it.

It is the value in the LIMIT of $x$ getting closer and closer to $1$ regardless of if it is defined in $1$ or defined just up to $1$ as in the case of the open set $(0,1)$.

But calculus:

The derivative of the function $f$ that is defined in the open interval is $$\frac{df}{dx}:(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx}(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x+h-x}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} 1=1$$

Which makes sense anyways, except when at $0$ and $1$. Luckily excluded.

This means that as $x$ changes, in whichever way, $f$ smoothly changes in exactly the same way, because it is a mapping $x \mapsto x$.

Another important property is of course that $f$ is continuous. This has to do with open sets, and with considering $f$ as mapping sets and not so much points and numbers: $$f^{-1}:(0,1) \to (0,1)$$ the inverse of a function is for one technically nicer. 
if open sets virtually portrayed by the action of $f$ into the target set are mapped back to the original domain then the result is always an open subset of the domain.
$f$ is also continuous and differentiable, and there's a theorem about local extremum points in open sets that says that the derivative must be exactly $0$ at these points (maximum points, minimum points) of $f$. But we got $1$ for the derivative everywhere in the open set. so there is no maximum..